# One liner code challenge

Tags: c#

I am trying to write a one liner code for the following code:

```
if (a.Count() == n)
{
    return a;
}
else if (a.Count() > n)
{
     Array.Resize(ref a, n);
     return a;
}
else
{
    return a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, n - a.Count())).ToArray();
}
```

I have tried this so far:

```
return a.Count() == n ? a :
 (a.Count() > n ? Array.Resize(ref a, n) : 
 a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, n - a.Count())).ToArray());
```

But as you can see it won't compile I can not figure out a way to replace the following code with one liner:

```
Array.Resize(ref a, n);
return a;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why on earth do you wanna put this complex code into a single line?! Extract a method with that logic and use that instead... Or even better put it into an extension method.

Comment: This could be for Code Golf. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @khlr I am not getting full marks because its a requirement to write less code as much as possible. So that's why I have to write a one liner code.

Comment: Seems a little odd to mark you down for that. Of course you need to write as DRY as possible, but I would argue to your tutor/lecturer/professor or whoever that making your code modular and reusable is more important.

Comment: @Syed is that a management goal? You (or your organization) will just earn one thing: unreadable code and maintainability nightmares... :-/

Comment: @Jezzabeanz Yeah you are write but the code is not for school, organization or even any personal project. Its Just code hunt :P

Comment: @khlr yes its unreadable but atm I have to write less code not readable. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0,n)).Take(n).ToArray();
```

or

```
Array.Resize(ref a, n); return a;
```

Comment: This is what i wanted, truly awesome. Thanks :D

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Added second variant.

Answer (score 2):

How about using `Take` method instead of `Array.Resize`:

```
return a.Count() == n ? a :
 (a.Count() > n ? a.Take(n).ToArray() : 
  a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, n - a.Count())).ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank You, this worked just fine but PetSerAl posted a better one liner than what I was originally trying to achieve. Thank you for you help :)

Comment: Simpler would be `return (a.Count() < n ? a.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, n - a.Count())) : a.Take(n)).ToArray();`